# Generating analog signal (PPM) Raspberry Pi

Tags: analog, raspberry-pi, pulse, protocol

I am trying to generate a PPM signal like the one used by RC receivers, using a raspberry pi.

I am using the pigpio library. Here's what I have so far.

Here's the header file:

```
short GAP;
short NO_WAVES;

typedef struct encoder_struct {
    int channel_count;
    unsigned int gpio;
    int frame_ms;
    int frame_us;
    int frame_s;
    int next_wave_id;
    struct timeval update_time;
    int wave_ids[3];
    gpioPulse_t *waves[3];
    unsigned int *widths;
} encoderStructy;

struct encoder_struct ppm_factory;

int init(unsigned int gpio, int channels, int frame_ms);
void update();
void update_channel(unsigned int channel, unsigned int width);
void update_channels(unsigned int *widths);
void destroy();
```

And here are the functions:

```
int init(unsigned int gpio, int channels, int frame_ms) {

    GAP = 300;
    NO_WAVES = 3;

    if (gpioInitialise() < 0) return 0;

    // Initialize all the variables in the PPM encoder structure
    ppm_factory.gpio = gpio;
    ppm_factory.channel_count = channels;
    ppm_factory.frame_ms = frame_ms;
    ppm_factory.frame_us = frame_ms * 1000;
    ppm_factory.frame_s = frame_ms / 1000;

    ppm_factory.widths = malloc(sizeof(int) * 8);

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        ppm_factory.waves[i] = malloc(6 * (channels + 1) * sizeof(gpioPulse_t));
    }
    // Set the pulse width of each channel to 1000
    for(int i=0; i<channels; i++) {
        ppm_factory.widths[i] = 1000;
    }

    // Set the wave ids to control value
    for(int i=0; i<NO_WAVES; i++) {
        ppm_factory.wave_ids[i] = -1;
    }

    // Set wave id counter
    ppm_factory.next_wave_id = 0;

    // Set GPIO pin to ground
    gpioWrite(gpio, PI_LOW);

    // Set the update time
    gettimeofday(&ppm_factory.update_time, NULL);

    return 0;
}

void update() {
    uint32_t  micros = 0;
    int i, wave_id;
    struct timeval remaining_time;


    // Set the first channel_count * 2 elements in the wave pulse (i.e lows and highs)
    for(i=0; i < ppm_factory.channel_count*2; i+=2) {
        ppm_factory.waves[ppm_factory.next_wave_id][i] = (gpioPulse_t){1u << ppm_factory.gpio, 0, GAP};
        ppm_factory.waves[ppm_factory.next_wave_id][i+1] = (gpioPulse_t){0, 1u << ppm_factory.gpio, ppm_factory.widths[i/2] - GAP};
        micros+=ppm_factory.widths[i];
    }

    // Fill with ground for the remaining time of the frame
    ppm_factory.waves[ppm_factory.next_wave_id][i] = (gpioPulse_t){1u << ppm_factory.gpio, 0, GAP};
    micros+=GAP;
    ppm_factory.waves[ppm_factory.next_wave_id][++i] =
            (gpioPulse_t){0, 1u << ppm_factory.gpio, ppm_factory.frame_us - micros};

    // Create the wave
    gpioWaveAddGeneric(i, ppm_factory.waves[ppm_factory.next_wave_id]);
    wave_id = gpioWaveCreate();

    // Send the wave to the wire
    gpioWaveTxSend(wave_id, PI_WAVE_MODE_REPEAT_SYNC);

    // Save the wave id in the array and increment the counter
    ppm_factory.wave_ids[ppm_factory.next_wave_id++] = wave_id;

    // Reset the counter when it reaches NO_WAVES
    if(ppm_factory.next_wave_id >= NO_WAVES) { ppm_factory.next_wave_id = -1; }

    struct timeval current_time;
    gettimeofday(&current_time, NULL);
    remaining_time.tv_sec = ppm_factory.update_time.tv_sec + ppm_factory.frame_s - current_time.tv_sec;
    remaining_time.tv_usec = ppm_factory.update_time.tv_usec + ppm_factory.frame_us - current_time.tv_usec;

    // Sleep for the remaining time
    if(remaining_time.tv_usec > 0) {
        gpioDelay(remaining_time.tv_usec);
    }

    // Update the timer
    gettimeofday(&ppm_factory.update_time, NULL);

    // Get next wave_id
    wave_id = ppm_factory.wave_ids[ppm_factory.next_wave_id];

    // Delete the next wave (by id) and clear the wave_id in the wave reference array
    if(wave_id != -1) {
        gpioWaveDelete(wave_id);
        ppm_factory.wave_ids[ppm_factory.next_wave_id] = -1;
        memset(ppm_factory.waves[ppm_factory.next_wave_id], 0 , (ppm_factory.channel_count + 1) * 2);
    }
}

void update_channel(unsigned int channel, unsigned int width) {
    ppm_factory.widths[channel] = width;
    update();
}

void update_channels(unsigned int *widths) {
    ppm_factory.widths = widths;
    update();
}

void destroy() {
    // Stop the current wave
    gpioWaveTxStop();

    // Clean all waves and wave_ids
    for(int i=0; i < NO_WAVES; i++) {
        if (ppm_factory.wave_ids[i] != -1) {
            gpioWaveDelete(ppm_factory.wave_ids[i]);
            ppm_factory.wave_ids[i] = -1;
        }
    }

    gpioTerminate();
}
```

And this is a typical function call:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    init(4, 8, 20);
    update_channel(0, 1500);
    destroy();
}
```

This is the result on the oscilloscope:
[image]

The problem is my code does not generate the final pause of (frame size - pulse train length) us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it, guys.

The `gpioAddGeneric` function is called with parameters `i` and `ppm_factory.waves[ppm_factory.next_wave_id]`.

If you can see, in my `for` loop, `i` is incremented up to `*`ppm_factory.channel count`. Then, incremented again when I add the wave. Therefore,`i` becomes channel_count * 2 + 1.

This was the mistake because we have channel_count * 2 + 2 pulses.

This works correctly now and generates the right signal.

Comment: You can express your ow answer to indicate that your problem is solved. Thanks for the update.